# is it possible to get incremental and hl search when using "q/" search window mode

Tags: search, command-line-window

I've been using the "q/" mode for all my searches recently because it allows quick and ease of access to previous searches, but it lacks the ability to perform incremental searches and highlighting that the default "/" search mode offers. Is this something that can be enabled or is it a limitation of using the search window?

The closest solution i can think of is to configure so that every search keystroke from "q/" jumps back into "/" mode, searches, and returns back to "q/" mode, but this feels expensive and inefficient.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Hi @filbranden do you have any thoughts on the direction I should head towards for this?

Comment: It's an interesting question, but I don't know of a way to implement it (maybe others will come up with a way to do it.) You can always file an issue on Vim's GitHub repository, so that this can be considered as a feature for a future Vim release.